# Unsolved PHP page refreshing without Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Please, can somebody publish a mistakes corrected and tested code for my problem? 
Program does - 22.php has the form. When the user enter and click Submit button, the result should be taken from 23.php and displayed in div on 22.php

I already tried solutions below and none of them solve my problem;

1) I changed to:  $("#testform").submit(function(event){

2) I included "return false;" at the end to prevent it to actually submit the form and reload the page.

3) clear my browser cache

I can see what happen the program with my computer;

1) I do not get error message after I click submit.

2) I can see the tab of the page reloads quickly and the entered text fields are cleared.

3) No error message or result shows.

```html
<html>    
    <head>
      <title>My first PHP page</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" 
         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {            
        $("#btn").click(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
           var myname = $("#name").val();
           var myage = $("#age").val();
           yourData ='myname='+myname+'&myage='+myage;
                $.ajax({
                  type:'POST',
                  data:yourData,//Without serialized                  
                  url: '23.php',
                  success:function(data) {
                     if(data){
                        $('#testform')[0].reset();//reset the form
   $('#result').val(data);
                        alert('Submitted');
                     }else{
                        return false;
                      }                        
                   };
                 });                    
            });             
         });
    </script>
   </head>
    <body>
      <form method="post" id="testform">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />Age:
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="btn" />
      </form>
 <div id='result'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['name']) ) { // was the form submitted?
    echo "Welcome ". $_POST["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "You are ". $_POST["age"] . "years old<br>";
}
```

?>

Comment: can you add var yourData?

Comment: I think in post method data should be an object, what's the output of console.log(data);

Comment: is the Ajax getting called?? Did u check using Firebug if the ajax is being called?? You can also find other js errors on load of the page using firebug. Sometimes due to tiny syntax errors, the whole js code doesn't work. So check it out once, and let me know.

Comment: your snippet has an error 
js:35 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: Thank you for all the guys. I have lack of knowledge about jQuery. @Govind (what's the output of console.log(data);) I do not understand what you ask. I am sorry. I will also google search about Firebug and try to give you a feedback result. Parthapratim Neog . Also I do not understand what this means "your snippet has an error js:35 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" .. I am so sorry for my fair knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formatting your post data like this inside your ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  data : {
     myname: myname
     myage: myage
  }
  ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Try removing the `;` in

```
 return false;
          }                    
       };
```

to

```
return false;
          }                    
       }
```

Comment: I made your modification. But no result and same as before. :(

Comment: @Kasuni Please check my comments in your question. Try out firebug. You might have some slight syntax error as well.

Comment: @Kasuni Try the edit that I just posted. I think that was the issue. You had syntax error

Comment: I solved the problem!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You are the expert. I removed ; and now it works well. For many days, I could not figure out this issue. Thanks a lot brother!!

Comment: Haha! Welcome bro. These are tiny issues. Make a practice of using Firebug. When using firebug, you will know these errors when you load the page. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

You are sending `myname` and checking `name`(`isset($_POST['name']`) in php.
don't use `.value()` use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) for data rendering. and console log the data and see whats request and response using firebug.
 Can you try this one?

To be changed

`var yourData ='name='+myname+'&age='+myage; // php is expecting name and age`

and

```
$('#result').html(data); // here html()
```

the code becomes

```
 $(document).ready(function() {            
    $("#btn").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
      var myname = $("#name").val();
       var myage = $("#age").val();
       var yourData ='name='+myname+'&age='+myage; // php is expecting name and age
            $.ajax({
              type:'POST',
              data:yourData,//Without serialized                  
              url: '23.php',
              success:function(data) {
                 if(data){
                    $('#testform')[0].reset();//reset the form
        $('#result').html(data); // here html()
                    alert('Submitted');
                 }else{
                    return false;
                  }                        
               }
             });
           });
         });
```

Comment: post request and response data from firebug or console.log(yourData) and console.log(data)

Comment: I am not yet familiar with firebug. Sorry. I do it soon and publish results

Comment: Does your page reload on submission?

Comment: Thank you anyway!! I Now the page does not reload and get the result. solved the problem by the @Parthapratim Neog

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to change your php code 
**try submit form with submit event ...**

```
$("#testform").submit(function(event){

use `dataType:json`; in your ajax ..

 yourData =$(this).serialize();
```

Your php

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['name']) ) { // was the form submitted?
   $data['name']= 'welcome '.$name;
   $data ['age']= 'you are '.$age;
print_r(json_encode($data));exit; 
}

?>
```

Now In Your Success function

```
var message = data.name + ' ' + data.age;
$('#result').html(message );
```

Comment: This will serialize the button not the form you need to use `$(this).closest('form').serialize();`

Comment: I have Update my answer dude please have a look .@Kasuni

Comment: Thank you anyway!! I solved the problem by the @Parthapratim Neog

Answer (score 1):

You can change at both end ajax and php:

#### @PHP:

You can check for correct posted data which is `myname` and `myage` not `name` and `age`.

```
<?php
if ( isset($_POST['myname'])) { // was the form submitted?
    echo "Welcome ". $_POST["myname"] . "<br>";
    echo "You are ". $_POST["myage"] . "years old<br>";
}
?>
```

or @Ajax:

```
yourData ='name='+myname+'&age='+myage;
//--------^^^^^^----------^^^^----change these to work without changing php
```

Just noticed the `#result` is an div element. So, you can't use `.val()` but use `.html(), .append()` etc:

```
$('#result').html(data);
```

Comment: Are you sure you are on `localhost` or any webserver? I hope you know you can't use ajax on filesystem but you need a server to test this.

Comment: I run on localhost . Thank you anyway!! I solved the problem by the @Parthapratim Neog